# How to retrieve data transfered by ajax to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I send an object to php file via json type successfully and write it to a .txt file as follows:

```
<script>
var buyInfo = {
  cartID : '123',
  sum : '456',
};

var data = new FormData();
data.append("data", JSON.stringify(buyInfo)); 
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new 
activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhr.open( 'post', './buy.php', true );
xhr.send(data);
</script>
```

However, I can not retrieve this data and assign it to a php variable for printing out as follows:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
$data = $_POST['data'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

$obj = json_decode($data);
print $obj->{'cartID'}; // cannot print out
}
echo file_get_contents('data.txt'); //can print out
?>
```

please show me the way. Thanks.

Comment: just do `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()` activeXObject is obsolete

Comment: You will need to use: `$obj->cartID`

Comment: @Brian but bracket notation should still work. If you do a var_dump on $_POST['data']; what do you see?

Comment: Hi Tommy, var_dump ( $_POST['data']) returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` method return a object, you can access to its attributes as:

```
$obj = json_decode($data);
print $obj->cartID;
```

or passing true as second parameter to get a array something like this:

```
$obj = json_decode($data, true);
print $obj['cartID'];
```

Comment: Hi, Jose, I try both cases and it still doesn't work

Comment: @TamNhan vardump the `$data` and `$obj` variable, what it is shown?

Comment: @TamNhan according with your comment above, `$_POST['data']` return NULL when you make a  `var_dump`, so it's not logic that `echo file_get_contents('data.txt'); //can print out` is printing the response, unless this has already created

Comment: My mistake, var_dump ( $_POST['data']) returns nothing.

Comment: @TamNhan I test your code in my local machine and it's working, so please look at your console in the browser if there is some error, you also can see if the folder has writing permission.